# Doctrine 2: selecting entity fields, including associated fields

Tags: php, rest, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="Employee")
 * 
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Project\BackendBundle\Entity\Repository\EmployeeRepository")
 */
class Employee
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Division")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="division_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Expose
     **/
    private $division;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Position")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="position_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $position;

    .....
}
```

With my REST API, I want to make the filter called "fields", where I put 
the comma separated list of entity fields, that I want to retrieve. Also I 
would like to be able to put associated fields there. So the request looks 
like this:

```
/api/employee?fields=id,division
```

I check these fields, if they exist in entity fields or association map.

Every associated field is added to the query like this:

```
foreach ( $this->assoc as $key => $mapping ) {
    $queryBuilder
        ->addSelect(substr($key, 0, 1) . ' AS ' . $key)
        ->leftJoin(
            $mapping['targetEntity'],
            substr($key, 0, 1),
            \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
            substr($key, 0, 1) . ' = u.' . $key
        );
}
```

From the request above I get the following DQL:

```
SELECT u.id, d AS division FROM Project\BackendBundle\Entity\Employee u LEFT JOIN Project\BackendBundle\Entity\Division d WITH d = u.division
```

Everything is fine, I get the expected result (`var_dump()`):

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'division' => 
        object(Project\BackendBundle\Entity\division)[645]
          private 'id' => int 20
          private 'name' => string 'division1' (length=9)
      'id' => int 890
```

Now if I add one more associated field to my requested fields:

```
/api/employee?fields=id,division,position
```

I get the following DQL:

```
SELECT u.id, d AS division, p AS position FROM Project\BackendBundle\Entity\Employee u LEFT JOIN Project\BackendBundle\Entity\Division d WITH d = u.division LEFT JOIN Project\BackendBundle\Entity\Position p WITH p= u.position
```

The results now looks like this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'division' => 
        object(Project\BackendBundle\Entity\Kategorija)[672]
          private 'id' => int 20
          private 'name' => string 'division1' (length=9)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'position' => 
        object(Project\BackendBundle\Entity\Position)[629]
          private 'id' => int 15
          private 'name' => string 'Manager' (length=7)
      'id' => int 890
```

The problem is that now the result of one entity lies in two arrays instead 
of one.

The expected result was:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'division' => 
        object(Project\BackendBundle\Entity\Kategorija)[672]
          private 'id' => int 20
          private 'name' => string 'division1' (length=9)
      'position' => 
        object(Project\BackendBundle\Entity\Position)[629]
          private 'id' => int 15
          private 'name' => string 'Manager' (length=7)
      'id' => int 890
```

What I am missing or doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I figured out that I am getting the fields wrong way. I started using PARTIAL functionality.

On request `/api/employee?fields=id,division` the DQL looks like this:

```
SELECT partial u.{id,division} FROM Project\BackendBundle\Entity\Employee u
```

And the result is:

```
array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'division' => 
            object(Project\BackendBundle\Entity\Kategorija)[672]
              private 'id' => int 20
              private 'name' => string 'division1' (length=9)
          'position' => 
            object(Project\BackendBundle\Entity\Position)[629]
              private 'id' => int 15
              private 'name' => string 'Manager' (length=7)
          'id' => int 890
```

You can see that I get the requested entity fields + all associated fields, no matter that I requested only one associated field.

How to get those associated fields filtered too?

Comment: Or you could just select needed employee (without complex queries), get an array of requested field names and pass it to JMS Serializer (which you most probably are using) as serialization groups. Also your entity would have defined these groups on the properties in the way that position would have a group "position", id would have a group "id" and so on. This way serializer would get only those properties from your entity which you passed as groups

Answer (score 0):

What command are you using to execute the DQL?  When you select 'division' or 'position' in a DQL statement, it's going to treat that as a full object.  If you select division.id and position.id that should work just fine.